# Shut down two instances of ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, shutdown

I need to properly shut down two instances of Executor Service in one method.

Here's my simplified code:

```
ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ScheduledExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
// logic here
executor1.shutdown();
executor2.shutdown();
try {
    if (!executor1.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        executor1.shutdownNow();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
}
try {
    if (!executor2.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        executor2.shutdownNow();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
}
```

`InterruptedException` is converted to `IllegalStateException` as I don't expect any interruptions here and this would mean my application went into illegal state.

I see one flaw in this solution - whenever first executor while shutting down throws exception, the second executor won't be properly closed. What should be correct approach here? How to safely close two instances of `ExecutorService`?

I'd rather like to avoid nested `try-finally` blocks, as I might need to add third executor service and code would become unmanageable.

Comment: Is this the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330464/running-multiple-thread-pools-executorservice-together ?

Comment: @YacoZaragoza not really - here my code sample is simplified, but I need two separate executor services, as one is normal, but second is scheduled executor service.

Comment: Got it.. Let me run some test :-)

Comment: When both shutdowns raise an exception, which one do you want to keep? If you want to keep both, you will need a wrapper exception to contain them.

Comment: Safe info if first faulted then handle second then throw  exception after last executor has been handled according to prior safed info.

Comment: @dhke one of them would be enough, second ideally could be suppressed. I'd prefer some utility for that, as I don't want to pollute my app with too much boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for a similar situation:

Apache Commons IO has a [`closeQuietly()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) that closes streams (or rather any `Closeable`) while ignoring any exception during close.

```
public void shutdownQuietly(ExecutorService executor)
{
    try {
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       /* IGNORE */
    }  
}
```

If you need those exception, you can try some slightly more evil trickery:

```
class MultiExecutorShutdown
{
     private final List<InterrupedException> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

     public void shutdown(ExecutorService service)
     {
         try {
             if (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                executor.shutdownNow();
             }
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             exceptions.add(ex);
         }
     }

     public Optional<InterruptedException> getLastException()
     {
         if (exceptions.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
         } else {
             return exceptions.get(exceptions.size() - 1);
         }
     }

     public Optional<InterruptedException> getFirstException()
     {
         if (exceptions.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
         } else {
             return exceptions.get(0);
         }
     }
}


[...]
MultiExecutorShutdown multiShutdown = new MultiExecutorShutdown();
multiShutdown.shutdown(executor1);
multiShutdown.shutdown(executor2);
multiShutdown.shutdown(executor3);

Optional<InterruptedException> exception = multiShutdown.getLastException();
// alternative:
// Optional<InterruptedException> exception = multiShutdown.getFirstException();

if (exception.isPresent()) {
   throw new IllegalStateException(exception.get());
}
```

If you also need the executor which failed, you can also modify `MultiExecutorShutdown` to keep an (ordered) map `ExecutorService -> Exception`.

You can also push the throw into `MultiExecutorShutdown` itself, making it even more usable. And finally the whole thing can --of course-- be abstracted so that it takes a functional, calls that and records any exceptions thrown.

Comment: If each of your three `ExecutorServices` throws an exception you will be unable to access them with first and last accessor methods only.

Comment: @harpun Correct. The implementation needs to be tailored to the specific use case. If you need all three exceptions, add the appropriate accessor method. You might even use a strategy pattern to make the resolution pluggable, but that may be overengineering the solution.